# How to play webm (using the VP9 codec) in VLC?

Tags: vlc, codecs

When I play a `.webm` file using the [**VP9 codec**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VP9) in VLC, I get the following error message (and the audio is played):

> VLC does not support the audio or video format "VP90". Unfortunately
>   there is no way for you to fix this.

I can play these files in totem, but how can I play them in VLC?

I'm on Ubuntu `14.04` and VLC is `2.1.6`. The package `ubuntu-restricted-extras` is installed.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/34372/how-to-play-a-webm-video-file

Comment: @KasiyA In the question you linked webm doesn't work in any player, but for me it works in totem. This is about VLC not playing it.

Comment: @Oli I added the version I'm using to the question.

Comment: The possible reason could be that, webm file contain an audio stream which is using a proprietary format. In that case, it will fail to produce audio. otherwise, vlc plays webm file fine

Comment: @AnwarShah The audio plays fine, the video using the codec `VP90` isn't working. (Other `.webm` files are working fine.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

VP9 requires VLC 2.2.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/trusty-media

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install vlc vlc-plugin-*
```

https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?t=131211

I had this problem in ubuntu 14.04 and it got solved by installing VLC 2.2.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to install `ubuntu-restricted-extras` to be able to play WebM with VLC. VLC 2.1.2 supports VP9 by default (see http://www.webmproject.org/vp9/ and http://www.videolan.org/vlc/releases/2.1.2.html). You might try upgrading VLC or installing the latest stable by downloading it from the VLC site directly.

Comment: I already have `VLC 2.1.4`.

Comment: Then I would suspect that it is an issue with the file itself. However, in my experience, VLC will play just about you give it.

Comment: Hmm, but totem can play these files without a problem. The videos are downloaded from YouTube with JDownloader.

Comment: I am getting this also on Ubuntu 14.04 with VLC 2.1.6. Weird, this was a straight VP9 download from YouTube.

Comment: “With the capabilities of "RinceWind", 2.1.2 allows experimental decoding of HEVC and Webm/VP9 (depending on the platform).”

Answer (score 2):

I've had to `apt remove vlc-?` before I found out that something from that package was playing havoc with HTML5 video ('vp9' codec)/DASH accelerated video rendering/streaming in `Firefox`.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to install restricted extras:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

That should work. But if it doesn't work after installing ubuntu-restricted-extras

Open Ubuntu Software center and search for "gstreamer" and install it.

Or open the terminal and type the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gstreamer-developers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gstreamer1.0*
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Do you know which `gstreamer` packages need to be installed? I'd rather not install [all of these](http://pastebin.com/Heq0TRfy) if possible.